# Multiple webpack entry points for React redux project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, react-redux

I want to create page wise bundle for react redux project.

How can we achieve this using webpack?

For simple react application we follows following way for multi entry

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'index' : './src/index.js',
    'contact' : './src/pages/contact.js'
  }
};
```

But how can we do same thing with react redux application.